# Implementing Swift protocol with a constrained type parameter

Tags: swift, generics

I have a couple of Swift protocols that describe a general interface that I'm trying to implement in multiple ways:

```
protocol Identifiable
{
    var identifier:String { get }
}

protocol ItemWithReference
{
    var resolveReference<T:Identifiable>(callback:(T) -> ())
}
```

Now I want to implement the `ItemWithReference` protocol using CloudKit as the back end (this will eventually work with an alternate back-end as well, at which time I expect to provide an alternative implementation of the `ItemWithReference` protocol.

In my CloudKit implementation, I have something like this:

```
class CloudKitIdentifiable : Identifiable
{
    ...
}

class CloudKitItemWithReference : ItemWithReference
{
    func resolveReference<T:Identifiable>(callback:(T) -> ())
    {
        // In this implementation, I want to only proceed if `T` is a CloudKitIdentifiable subtype
        // But not sure how to enforce that
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to constrain `T` to be a `CloudKitIdentifiable` rather than just a simple `Identifiable`. I can't do that directly in the `resolveReference` declaration because then the function wouldn't conform to the `ItemWithReference` protocol. So instead, I am hoping to confirm that T is indeed a `CloudKitIdentifiable` and then invoke it's initializer to create a new instance of the class being resolved.

Is there any way in Swift to use T's metatype `T.Type` and determine if it is a subtype of another type? Furthermore, is there any way to invoke a required initializer that has been declared on that subtype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
class CloudKitIdentifiable : Identifiable {
    var identifier:String = ...

    required init() {}
    // you need `required`.
}

class CloudKitItemWithReference : ItemWithReference {

    func resolveReference<T:Identifiable>(callback:(T) -> ()) {
        if T.self is CloudKitIdentifiable.Type {
            // do work..
            let obj = (T.self as CloudKitIdentifiable.Type)()
            callback(obj as T)
        }
    }
}
```

OR:

```
class CloudKitItemWithReference : ItemWithReference {
    func resolveReference<T:Identifiable>(callback:(T) -> ()) {
        if let CKT = T.self as? CloudKitIdentifiable.Type {
            // do work..
            let obj = CKT()
            callback(obj as T)
        }
    }
}
```

But, In this case, you have to call `resolveReference` like this:

```
let ref = CloudKitItemWithReference()
ref.resolveReference { (obj: CloudKitIdentifiable) -> () in
    //                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ explicit type is necessary.
    println(obj.identifier)
    return
}
```

Rathar than that, I would recommend to use [Associated Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189):

```
protocol Identifiable {
    var identifier:String { get }
}

protocol ItemWithReference {

    typealias Item: Identifiable // <-- HERE is associated type

    func resolveReference(callback:(Item) -> ())
}

class CloudKitIdentifiable : Identifiable {
    var identifier:String
    init(identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
    }
}

class CloudKitItemWithReference : ItemWithReference {

    // `Item` associated type can be inferred from
    // the parameter type of `resolveReference()`
    //
    // typealias Item = CloudKitIdentifiable

    func resolveReference(callback:(CloudKitIdentifiable) -> ()) {
        let obj = CloudKitIdentifiable(identifier: "test")
        callback(obj)
    }
}

let ref = CloudKitItemWithReference()
ref.resolveReference { obj in
    println(obj.identifier)
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rintaro. Your first approach did the trick for me. I didn't go with the associated type approach because, while I agree that it is cleaner in general, it becomes more difficult when the class implementing the protocol (`CloudKitItemWithReference` in this case) is a base class that will be further subclassed and its item type will be a subclass of `CloudKitIdentifiable`.